# Remove border around QMainWindow (PyQt)

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I have created a frameless window with a border radius in pyqt. However after applying both setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint),
setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True) in the constructor,
I am left with this border around the window:

[image: border around window]

This is the stylesheet for the main window

```
MainWindow.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 20px;")
```

Any suggestions on what might be causing this?

Comment: Did you try setting `border-color: transparent`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have tried your idea but it did not remove the border, i just found out that simply setting color: transparent; does the trick.

Comment: @MDaniel112 use generic stylesheet properties with care. In your case, you're applying the border radius to **all** widgets in the main window (including possible QDialogs created with that window as parent), and in certain situations can even cause graphic issues or incoherency with other stylesheets, especially for some complex widgets. Selectors should be preferred, so use `setStyleSheet("QMainWindow { border-radius: 20px; }")`.

Comment: Thanks for the answear! And for the suggestion to use selectors.